# Sequence of holomorphic functions $f_n \to f$ uniformly. Existence of an open set with good properties

Tags: complex-analysis

let $U$ be a domain   and $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$  $f_n$  be a  sequence of  holomorphic functions on $U$  that converge uniformaly  to
$f$ on every  compact set $K\subset U$.
assume that $f$ is not identicaly zero and $z_0 \in U $.
1)show that $\exists r > 0$ such that $\overline D(z_0,r) \subset  U$ and $\forall z\in C(z_0,r)$ we have  $f(z)\neq 0$
2)show that $\exists \alpha  > 0 /$ $\forall z\in C(z_0,r)$ we have $|f(z)|\geq \alpha $
and $ \forall n>N$ $|f_n(z)|\geq \frac{\alpha}{2} $

my attempt:
For the first we use the fact that $U$ is a domain and $f$ is not identicaly zero.
And for the second one since $\forall z\in C(z_0,r)$ we have  $f(z)\neq 0$ then $\exists \alpha  > 0 /$ $\forall z\in C(z_0,r)$ we have $|f(z)|\geq \alpha $
Is this correct?

Comment: It is given that $f(z_0)\neq0$, right? Oh, never mind, maybe the $C(z_0,r)$ is the circle of radius $r$.

Comment: Is the first $U$ the same set as the second one?

Comment: @owl yyes C is a circle of radius r

Comment: A domain is open, typically, so how can it be compact? Your claims are correct, but you have provided zero justification.

Comment: @TedShifrin sorry $f_n$ converge on a compact subset $K$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos edited

Comment: Don’t you mean uniform convergence on *every* (not *some*) compact set? If the compact set is a few points, you won’t get anywhere.

Comment: every compact set

Comment: You need to be very careful to proofread and write carefully. Anyhow, edit to add details of proofs of your claims.

Comment: Well , This is night and I don't want to comment Unless I can say many ideas here are partially correct.

Comment: You should read the proofs of Complex Analysis first.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order it reflects at least a little the content of the question, therefore able to attract the attention of further readers.